# OpenVPN and oLDAP configuration

Tags: linux, vpn, openldap, opendirectory

I have a Linux VM setup with OpenVPN on Debian 7.8. I copied the client files over to my MacBook and iPhone and I'm successfully able to create a VPN connection without any issues. However, I'd like to also integrate openLDAP authentication with the certificates to add an extra layer of security. Is something like this common or is a certificate usually all that is needed?

The openLDAP integration would be against my Open Directory server on Mac OS X Server 10.10 (Yosemite). I'm not that knowledgeable with openLDAP so how would I go about configuring it on the Linux VM and modifying the client.conf to auth against it?